# Connect 3 PCs in chain

Tags: networking, 15.04

I've got 3 PCs with 2 network adapters each - I want to make a cluster from them, but first I need to connect all of them into one network. My idea is to connect first PC to router, share Internet connection to second one, connect second PC to first and share Internet connection to third one. So far so good, I succeed connecting 1st and 2nd PC, 3rd one is failing to communicate - by the way, after connecting ethernet cable to third one, 2nd often disconnects from Internet connection. I always share by setting IPv4 to "Share to other computers". There is (as far as I see) no matter in choosing which PC is which - always 1st and 2nd can connect and third PC in chain cannot.

Any ideas how can I to connect them? (I use Ubuntu Desktop 15.04)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too isolated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We used to do that 35 years ago using [10Base2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10BASE2): just daisy chain a bunch of computers together.

*In the mean time, technology has evolved a bit*, so today, I would use [10Base-T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10Base-T) and just plug all 3 computers into a switch (or hub or VLAN), which will give you what you want straight away without any of the head-aches linked to daisy-chaining.

If you insist on using 10Base-2 to daisy-chain, there are a few particularities using that technology, so read [the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10BASE2), and **please: don't use 10Base-T to daisy chain!**

Comment: LAN gamers will already know this!

Comment: As you're a reputation 13 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**